# use external functions to calculate value in eloquent queries

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

I have created a filter for products in laravel 5.5

I want to filter the price range (min:max) but the price column in db is not the price that i am using to show on product page.

I have 2 more columns TVA, Profit and an external function that calculate the price for sale.

The calcPrice function take those arguments (price, tva, profit)

```
calcPrice($price, $tva = 0, $profit = 0)
```

In the controller for filters logic i use this approach:

```
// Product model
$products = Product::query();
// use for appends with pagination
$queries = [];
// all the conditions for the query
$filterCondition = array(
        ['IsActive', '1'],
        ['CategoryID', $currentCategory->CategoryID]
    );
// brand filter
if(request()->has('brand')){
   $filterBrands = explode(":", request('brand'));
   $products = $products->whereIn('BrandID', $filterBrands);
   $queries['brand'] = request('brand');
}
...
// price filter
if(request()->has('price')){
   $filterPrice = explode(":", request('price'));
   $min = $filterPrice[0];
   $max = $filterPrice[1]; 
   $products = $products->whereBetween('Price', [$min, $max]);
   $queries['price'] = request('price');           
}

// the final query
$products = $products->where($filterCondition)->paginate(9)->appends($queries);
```

Is there a way to calculate the final price in select in eloquent?

ex: calcPrice(Price, TVA, Profit) as finalPrice then use the finalPrice field to compare between

**UPDATE**

using

```
$products = DB::table('products')->select(DB::raw('products.*, (Price * ((TVA + Profit) / 100 + 1)) as salePrice'));
```

instead of

```
$products = Product::query();
```

i see the value salePrice in dd but.....when using to compare:

`$products->whereBetween('salePrice', [$min, $max])`;

says that column salePrice not found. How can i use that 'salePrice 'allias as a column?

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
$products->whereRaw('(Price * ((TVA + Profit) / 100 + 1)) >= ?', [$min])
    ->whereRaw('(Price * ((TVA + Profit) / 100 + 1)) <= ?',  [$max])
```

Comment: using having in price filter:  $products = $products->having('salePrice', '>=' , $min);` => `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'salePrice' in 'having clause' `

Comment: I just saw that you are using pagination. Unfortunately pagination doesn't support `HAVING` clauses. I updated my answer with a different solution.

Comment: seems to work for filter :) thx.  Probably the same approach for order `$products->orderBy('Price', 'asc');`

Comment: Yes. Unfortunately we have to calculate the same price multiple times.